# What does `<-`, `>-`, `<+`, `>+` in python mean?

Tags: python

I came across a post with these "conditional operators" (im not sure) using `<-`, `>-`, `<+`, `>+` I have never seen this before, and I am really wondering what it does.

```
>>> 1 <- 2
False
>>> 1 >- 2
True
>>> 1 <+ 2
True
>>> 1 >+ 2
False
```

Can please someone explain?

Comment: ... what does `< -` mean in `1 < -2`?

Comment: Ignore the spacing. Pretend you have, for example, `1<-2`. It's the same as `1 < -2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Behold the confusion that arises due to silly spacing.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator)

Compilers and interpreters tend to ignore whitespaces while parsing/interpreting instructions. You don't see code the same way a compiler/interpreter does.

Is not `1 <- 2` the same as `1<-2`? After all, what does a whitespace mean in arithmetic? Now since whitespace doesn't count for anything, let's add whitespaces, but a little more smartly:

```
1 < -2
```

There we go, all better now. Doesn't that make more sense? In future, try adding parenthesis to your statements, if noticing obvious patterns isn't your strong suit...

```
1 < (-2)
```

That doesn't change anything, but now it's a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0):

When you mention `1 <- 2` in your sample code,
it is actually checking the condition `1 < -2` which returns `False`. Thus, of course, unfortunately you are not correct.
You must have been studying compound operators too much.